# How to implement a clustering process, using a genetic algorithm in python?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, genetic-algorithm

I'm a novice in python coding.
I have a question regarding clustering using genetic algorithm in python.

I would like to cluster the station based on not only distance but also the other index of the cluster. I want to maximize the total index of all clusters.
I have 900 bike stations GPS coordinate data.

[image: 900 number of bike stations in Seoul]

I have already created a distance matrix of [all stations] x [all stations]. Units are in [km].

### Basic idea - draw random circles of clusters.

If I want to cluster in 50 clusters, then the code should generate 50 different circles of clusters. The station inside the circle<sub>***n***</sub>, it will be labeled in cluster<sub>***n***</sub>. The example is shown in the image below

[image: basic idea to generate circle]

There are some restrictions to generate circles,

1. the cluster circles should not be overlapping.
    - to satisfy this condition, distance between two center of the circles should be larger than the sum of radii. ( but I don't know how to code with python )
2. the radius of circle limits in size. ( It should be found in hyperparameter, but minimum of 1 km and maximum of 4 km is the first candidate )
3. While clustering, stations that cannot go into the circle cluster will occur. For this case we should allocate these stations to the nearest circle based on the distance.

After we successfully generate the random not overlapping 50 cluster circles, I want to find the best combination of the circles which can maximize my own index.

### Genetic algorithm

**`gene`** : `{ x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2, x3, y3, r3, ... x50, y50, r50 }`
**`[ xn, yn ]`** is the center of the circle and **`rn`** is the radius of the circle.

The center of the cluster should be a station rather than a point within the map. Meaning that each 50 clusters center point should be a station.

**`rn`** generate randomly within the boundary.

For example, if I want to make a cluster `1km < rn < 4km`, than **`r`** can be generated randomly in a 100 [m] interval.

So, **`r`** can get a values like in `{ 1.1km, 1.2km, ... 3.9km, 4km }`

Division point will be:

```
{ x1, y1, r1,/ x2, y2, r2,/ x3, y3, r3,/ ... / x50, y50, r50 }
```

Fitness function is my own index of the cluster that I mentioned.

I already have a code to calculate the index. If stations are labeled by the cluster number, then I can calculate it with a pre-built code.

Labeling form should be like csv file below:

[image: cluster labeling form]

Sorry for the long explanation, and thank you!!!!

Comment: It sounds like you are inventing your own clustering algorithm. Before you do this, have you considered an existing algorithm? If one of them works for you then you will find a lot more resources online and have to do less work. [Scikit-learn has a good comparison.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html)

Comment: Evolutionary approaches are not particularly well suited for clustering. There are various reasons for this, in particular the lack of a good quality measure for selection.

Comment: It seems easier to do it with K-Means algorithm.

Comment: Also, is that data available online?